# Is it possible to get name of variables passed as `params object[]`?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder, if it is possible to get the names of variables passed to method via `params object[] values`?

The signature of method looks like this:

```
public static void ExecuteSafely(
    Action callback,
    string command,
    params object[] values)
{
    // code here
}
```

I was trying to get the values with `nameof(values[index])`, but it tells me:

> Expression does not have a name.

The point of this is to dynamically add parameters to SQL command, and it would be easier and less parameters to pass if I could add them based on the names of **params**, but the number of those params should be variable.

Can you recommend any solution or another approach to this?

Comment: Use a dictionary, or an anonymous object.

Comment: @poke You mean instead of `object` like `(string name, object value)` ?

Comment: A dictionary, i.e. `Dictionary<string, object>`, or just a single `object` on which you use reflection to retrieve the property names and values. So you either call the method `Foo(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["foo"] = 2, ["bar"] = "hello" })` or `Foo(new { foo = 2, bar = "hello" })`

Comment: Seems legit, i'll try it out

Comment: There has got to be a way to do this right? I'm looking through a new StackTrace() and it's frames, methods, ParameterInfos, etc and... no luck. I guess when the compiler compiles the code, the variables converted to an object array and the names of those variables are not retained in the stack trace? But maybe they're in there somewhere?!?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that's not possible. `nameof` is a compile time feature and you want the name of variables at runtime(an array could be created dynamically).

If names are important for you use a `Dictionary<string, object>` or with [C#7 a named tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples):

```
public static void ExecuteSafely(Action callback, string command, 
    params (string name, object value)[] commandParameters)
{
    foreach ((string Name, object Value) commandParameter in commandParameters)
    {
        string name = commandParameter.Name;
        object value = commandParameter.Value;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Call it in this way:

```
ExecuteSafely(yourAction, "CreateUser", ("UserName", "Tim Schmelter"));
```

Comment: I made it using tuples, thanks a lot, i'll accept answer in 5 min